# Imagick:: cropThumbnailImage function blur text on image

Tags: php, imagick

I am generating image using Imagick:: cropThumbnailImage function.
Image having text on it. After image creation the text will blur.

My PHP Code

```
    $imagick1 = new Imagick($mainImagePath);
    $imagick1->cropThumbnailImage(400, 400);
    $imagick1->writeImage($photobuilder_file);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Imagick::setImageCompressionQuality ( int $quality ); check this

Comment: And nothing has changed?

Comment: If you already use that, please update your code to truly reflect what you are doing. Also, you don't mention whether your image is JPEG or PNG, nor provide an example of how it looks before and after. Nor do you tell us your ImageMagick version. Come on! If you want folks to help you, make it easy for them :-)